# Is there an existing Quarkus function to deserialise a CloudEvent from a JSON String?

Tags: deserialization, quarkus, objectmapper, cloudevents

I am currently working with Quarkus, and I encountered an issue while wanting to deserialise a JSON String message recieved through a WebSocket to a CloudEvent.

Using the **Quarkus ObjectMapper** doesn't work since the Quarkus CloudEvent stack is using private classes and a builder to instantiate CloudEvents. I can't then use the following :

```
public CloudEvent<?> createCloudEvent(String message) throws JsonProcessingException {
    return objectMapper.readValue(message, SimpleCloudEvent.class);
}
```

I tried eluding this issue with this :

```
public CloudEvent<?> createCloudEvent(String message) throws JsonProcessingException {
    return objectMapper.readValue(message, CloudEventBuilder.create().build(null).getClass());
}
```

But this time the mapper cannot deserialise the headers that are not part of the CloudEvent specification into the *extensions* field, as the SimpleCloudEvent constructor doesn't have any explicit field for every possible header.

Nevertheless, using Funqy Knative in another project, I still assume that the Quarkus ObjectMapper can deserialise String or JSON objects to CloudEvents. The following code snippet might explain why I think that :

```
@Funq
public void receiveCloudEvent(CloudEvent<String> cloudEvent) {
    //do something with the received CE
}
```

Here, what is sent to my application is an HTTP request, that ultimately is a JSON object. Therefore, either the Quarkus framework or the Funqy Knative one is able to translate it to a **valid SimpleCloudEvent**, even containing the headers that are not part of the CloudEvent specification in the *extensions* map.

Does anyone know what class/function the framework is using and if they are usable ?

Or should I really just make a custom deserializer ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knative Funq should indeed deserialize JSON Values (Object,String,Number,Boolean,Array,Null).

Your example:

```
@Funq
public void receiveCloudEvent(CloudEvent<String> cloudEvent) {
    //do something with the received CE
}
```

This function expects JSON String (not Object) as data.
Example of valid invocation via `cURL`:

```
curl "http://localhost:8080" \    
  -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
  -H "Ce-Id:42" \
  -H "Ce-Source:sample-source" \
  -H "Ce-Type:sample-input" \
  -H "Ce-Specversion:1.0" \
  -d '"json string"'
```

Note the quotation marks in data.

Example for JSON Object could be:

```
public class Person {
    public String name;
    public int age;
}

public void receiveCloudEvent(CloudEvent<Person> cloudEvent) {
    //do something with the received CE
}
```

`cURL` invocation:

```
curl "http://localhost:8080" \    
  -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
  -H "Ce-Id:42" \
  -H "Ce-Source:sample-source" \
  -H "Ce-Type:sample-input" \
  -H "Ce-Specversion:1.0" \
  -d '{"name": "John", "age": 42 }'
```

Lastly there is an escape hatch when you want to deserialise by yourself using `byte[]`:

```
public void receiveCloudEvent(CloudEvent<byte[]> cloudEvent) {
    // deserialize data from byte array
}
```

The Funq serialization/deserialization is private. If you want something more open look at https://github.com/cloudevents/sdk-java.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Quarkus.

You need to look at Jackson. If you google: Jackson and builder pattern, you will find enough information about this problem.

Or you might also need to look at Jackson mixins, if CloudEvent is coming as a 3rd party lib.